# How to read and write values in excel using java?

Tags: java, excel, report, apache-poi

> - Sample Excel --> Sorry I'm not allowed to attached a image..
> - TC No. | Title | **Result**
> - 1 | State and Vin | **Failed**
> - 2 |  State and Reg Code | **Passed**
> - 3 |  Booking a Test Drive | **Passed**

```
public class sampleTest{
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
         int iTest = 2, iTest2 = 3;
          if (iTest == iTest2){
              //It will pass a value into the excel (e.g. "Passed")
          }
          else{
             //It will pass a value into the excel (e.g. "Failed")
          }
    }
```

My program's goal is to generate a report by getting the Passed and Failed results from my tests. My main problem here is on how to read the results from the excel and place the value **"Passed"** or **"Failed"** under **Result column**.

Comment: You can alternatively create a CSV file with the fields that you mentioned and open the csv file with excel.

Comment: I already have an existing excel file. What I need to do is to write "Passed" or "Failed" under the Result column. By the way, I can't use csv file because I need to create a pie chart within the excel file.

Comment: I have edited my answer to demonstrate how to open a xls file and read the content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Via library that will be your interface to Excel document. One option is [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/). Excel example code can be found from [here](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#sxssf).

Other option is [Java Excel API](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jexcelapi/).

Answer (score 1):

Download the apache poi jar from [here](http://poi.apache.org/download.html)
Go through these [examples](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/examples.html) which demonstrates how to read/write xls data from a java program
Sample help code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(); 
        Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("sheet");
        Row row = sheet.createRow((short) 0);

        row.createCell(0).setCellValue(1.2);
        row.createCell(1).setCellValue(wb.getCreationHelper().createRichTextString("This is a string"));
        row.createCell(2).setCellValue(true);

        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("workbook.xls");
        wb.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();
    }
```

This might help you to get started.
The whole flow is:

1. Create a workbook => The main xls file
2. Then create a sheet
3. Then create a row.
4. For each row create as many cells as you want and fill the cells with different values
5. Write the workbook like a file.

There can be multiple type of cells see [this](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CellTypes) for more info.
To know how to read an excel file:

```
InputStream myxls = new FileInputStream("workbook.xls");
        wb     = new HSSFWorkbook(myxls);


         sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);       // first sheet
         row     = sheet.getRow(0);        // third row
        HSSFCell cell   = (HSSFCell) row.getCell((short)1);  // fourth cell
        if (cell.getCellType() == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
            System.out.println("The Cell was a String with value \" " + cell.getStringCellValue()+" \" ");
        } else if (cell.getCellType() == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
            System.out.println("The cell was a number " + cell.getNumericCellValue());
        } else {
            System.out.println("The cell was nothing we're interested in");
        }
```

For more info see [this](http://onjava.com/onjava/2003/04/16/poi_excel.html)

Comment: Thanks for that idea. however I already have an existing excel file created - so what I need to do is to write "Passed" or "Failed" under the Result column. i don't know how can i get the exact column so that i can insert the value "Passed" or "Failed" status. I will just read all the answers that was given by -didxga and -Mikko Maunu.